# Set report field value in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports, c#-2.0

I have a report field where its value is "2". I need to display in report as "True" if report field value is 2.How do i do this in Formula editor crystal reports ? Please help me.

EDIT :Here is my code in formual Editor: 
    if( {emp.company_id}=2) Then
       CStr ({emp.company_id}) ="ABC pvt ltd"

As emp.company_id is integer value i have tried converting it to string but still it displays as 2 in report.

Answer (score 1):

All you need in the formula is

```
{Tablename.Fieldname}=2
```

Answer (score 1):

What I don't know is what you want to display if it isn't 2. Assuming you want to display the original value then you need to add a formula to your report, as follows:

```
if ({emp.company_id}=2) then "true"
else cstr({emp.company_id})
```